# Monitor signal turns off for several seconds after Windows 7 start-up screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display, windows-registry

Background:

I have been having some problems with my Windows registry today. It looked like antivirus had corrupted my licensing data. When I booted in to windows I would receive a message about:

"an unauthorized change was made to windows 7"

and telling me I needed to repair it. I followed lots of tips from windows forums, but I just kept hitting permission errors and nothing worked. Anyway, I managed to fix this by using an activation crack.

However, when I now boot-up Windows, just after the password screen (I dont bother with a password on my home PC) the signal to my monitor cuts off temporarily for a few seconds, and then turns back on again.

I installed the latest driver for my graphics card, but the problem still exists. It must be something to do with the registry/the activation crack did.

What could I do to repair this? When I had the initial problem I did use a Windows 7 repair disk and the startup repair tool, but it couldn't find any problem.

Update:

Found this which is the same issue:

http://www.overclock.net/t/1487225/monitor-turns-off-briefly-then-back-on-after-starting-windows

and somebody replied:

> As far as I know its basically happens because the systems switches
>   over form "driverless mode" to using the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Whats with the downvote??

Comment: Could it be caused by a resolution change? Like for example when you switch to a lower res using Windows "Display" does it take that long for the monitor to figure it out and display the new res?

Comment: Hi, i never had this problem before the registry issue. Is there anywhere in the registry which could be responsible for this behaviour?